# Access DB VBA 'No current record error' using Form_BeforeUpdate(Cancel As Integer)

Tags: vba, ms-access

Hi I have following code for Form before update in Access but it is throwing error 'No current record error'. Any help would be appreciated. Job Checks is Combo Box and Comments is long Text box. Code is working fine apart this error.

```
Private Sub Form_BeforeUpdate(Cancel As Integer)
If ([Job Checks] = "Moderate" And Nz([Comments]) = "") Then
MsgBox "You need to fill out Comments"
Comments.SetFocus
Cancel=True
End If 
End Sub
```

Comment: At which line occurs the error? What does "working fine" mean?

Comment: If comments is empty when Job Checks is "Moderate" it will not let me save the records and trigger MsgBox error followed by second error "No current record.". When I fill the comments box it will save the records without an issue.

Comment: So how do you save the record? At which line occurs the error?

Comment: Command button click event 'DoCmd.GoToRecord , , acNewRec' Me.Dirty = False

Comment: OK. That is unrelated to your posted function. A new record is not Dirty, and you can't "undirty" a record that it not Dirty. Check for `Me.NewRecord`.

Comment: Thank you I think the problem is with my Save and clear button rather Form Before update 'Private Sub Command32_Click()'
'On Error Resume Next'
'Me.Dirty = False' 
'If Err.Number = 0 Then'
'DoCmd.GoToRecord , , acNewRec'
'Else: MsgBox Err.Description, vbCritical, "Error"'
'End If'
'End Sub'

Answer (score 0):

Try using the controls rather than the fields:

```vb
Private Sub Form_BeforeUpdate(Cancel As Integer)

    If Me![Job Checks].Value = "Moderate" And Nz(Me!Comments.Value) = "" Then
        MsgBox "You need to fill out Comments."
        Me!Comments.SetFocus
        Cancel = True
    End If 

End Sub
```

Comment: Tried this still the same issue first populate MsgBox "You need to fill out Comments" then followed with second error "No current record."